# Post authorization doesn't work

Tags: express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to restrict ability for one user to edit someone else's posts. 
When I click 'Edit post' it change the author of the post, is it because of 'save' method or ?
Here is my attempt:

```
router.put('/posts/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt'), (req, res) => {

Post.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, post) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (post.author = req.user._id) {
        post.title = req.body.title,
        post.content = req.body.content,
        post.postImageUrl = req.body.postImageUrl

        post.save((err, updatedPost) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
                res.json({message:'You have successfully updated your post', success: true});
            }
        });

    } else {
        res.json({success: false, message: 'You are not allowed to do this.'});
    }
});
```

});

I checked post.author and req.user._id, they match.

Comment: Shouldn't this `if (post.author = req.user._id) `  be `if (post.author == req.user._id) ` ?

Comment: That was a problem, but now it returns that author and user are not match, although they are..

Comment: Are they both string?Can you give a sample of the values?

Comment: `post.author` is a reference, `req.user._id` is a object property..

Comment: I strongly suspect that both post.author and req.user._id may be representing different things.Can you help by elaborating your question by posting examples of post and user documents that is stored in mongo.

Comment: User: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a4a9bff0eee676e14b31ab9"), "username" : "hazard ", "name" : "E", "email" : "hd@gmail.com", "password" : "$2a$10$Lfh8F63hdcwOvOqvLCt2UO865B0L2", "avatar" : "http://www.expat.com//forum/img/avatars/151664.jpg?v=1436269674", "__v" : 0 }` , `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a4a9c370eee676e14b31aba"), "title" : "alonsos post title", "content" : "\"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasur", "postImageUrl" : "https://www.powtoon.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/3.jpg", "author" : ObjectId("5a4b61476299c0b01da89ce1"), "comments" : [  ], "__v" : 8 }`

Comment: There is a mongoose method `.equals`, now it works. Thank you for your effort

Comment: Updated your question as well as my answer so that the next person with the same problem will find the answer quickly rather than reading the entire comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your condition for checking if the current user is the post's author.Instead of checking for equality you are trying to assign and change the author value.

`if (post.author = req.user._id)`

**Solution:**

Mongoose offers a `.equals` method for checking equality for object ids.Here is the link for the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals) for mongodb-native driver `.equals` method, which is used by Mongoose.

`if (post.author.equals(req.user._id))`